# Recognize numbers in speech - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, numbers, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a timer that could be set by speech.

My only problem is that I'm lazy to hard code every (example : "x minutes","x hours"...)

Is there a way to make the speech recognizer recognize numbers(Numbers up to 60 are enough.)?

Just one of my pitiful tries:

```
Public WithEvents numrec As New Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")) 
Public gram As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument 
Public NumRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("nums")
Public ComList As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf(1,2,3,4,...,60) 'Ofcourse this code won't work
```

Comment: I could actually use a for loop.. I'll try it and write back!

Comment: The loop didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this question today 12-3-2018.  Are you still interested in a solution? I have written some code in VB.net that I believe would solve your problem.

In my case I have one column in a datagridview that has anywhere from 1 to 5 digit numbers (as many as 800 of them). These numbers are loaded into memory at the start with a loop.  After the Speech Recognition is activated (with the click of a button).  You call out the number, the number is selected and highlighted.  You then say "NOW" (also loaded into the end of the limited vocabulary) and the System time is inserted into the same row as the highlighted number but a different column.

Ed